# G++ allows for implicit long-to-int truncation on x64

Tags: c++, g++, overflow, integer-overflow

I compile this code with g++ -Wall, get no warnings/errors:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
        long x = 1000000000000;
        int y = x;
        printf("%ld %d\n", x, y);
        return 0;
}
```

The output is something one would expect:

```
1000000000000 -727379968
```

But shouldn't the compiler prevent from implicit conversion/truncation in this case?

```
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)
```

Comment: *Prevent* it ? How about *warn* you about it? (You do have warnings turned on, right? It says you do, but none are emitted? not even "potential loss of data" type warnings?)

Comment: That's correct. I tried using -Wconversion I just found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263267/why-does-c-allows-implicit-conversion-from-int-to-unsigned-int, but the code still compiles silently.

Comment: How odd. Now I have to try this on my clang. Your gcc is older than dirt, but I'm somewhat taken-back something like this isn't caught. Edit: clang catch this immediately "Implicit conversion loses integer precision". just fyi.

Comment: `-Wall` doesn't cover all warnings. If you want more warnings, you could use clang and the flag `-weverything`

Comment: And - yes, I was expecting g++ to prevent me from potential data loss. Just the way it wouldn't allow to assign a double to an integer.

Comment: Both of those (assigning a double to an int and this) aren't compile-time killers (unless you're compiling with -Werror), but you should at least be getting a conversion warning(s) (save for the case where `long` and `int` are the same size on your platform, which the standard supports)

Comment: However, assigning double _does_ prevent the code from compiling. I also tried using long long instead of long - still no warnings.

Comment: Well, you're not hallucinating. I found a gcc 4.2 on my Darwin rig and it exhibits the same symptoms regarding `-Wall -Wconversion`. However neither it nor clang abort the compile on a `double` assigned to an `int`, even with both. This may seem odd, but did you try `Wshorten-64-to-32` (its pretty obvious what it does, but it may  not be in 4.1). That *does* issue a warning on my 4.2 kit: "warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value"

Comment: I got warning with gcc4.7.1/clang3.3 once x is const or constexpr.

Comment: Just tried Wshorten-64-to-32, got 'unrecognized command line option'. Probably, it appeared in 4.2? And thanks for doing this research!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `-Wconversion` which is NOT included in the `-Wall`. I definitely got the warning in g++ 4.4 and 4.5 but I don't have access to test earlier versions. `warning: conversion to 'int' from 'long long int' may alter its value` (I used `long long` because I was generating a 32 bit build where long is still 32 bits).

Comment: +1 That would explain it. I never knew that wasn't covered in -Wall. Good to know, Mark. Thanks!

Comment: Still no luck:
`$ g++ overflow.cpp -Wall -Wconversion && ./a.out
1000000000000 -727379968`

Comment: Or, so it really seems to have to do with my older-then-dirt compiler like WhozCraig suggested earlier. Thanks Mark B!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: it appears that `-Wconversion` is not included either in `-Wextra` nor in `-pedantic` (GCC 4.7). I have to admit I'm kinda baffled by this, here's one more flag I'll have to add to my usual ones. +1