# How to prevent implicit conversion from int to unsigned int?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, unsigned-integer

Suppose you have this:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(unsigned int x) : x(x) {}
    unsigned int x;
};

int main() {
    Foo f = Foo(-1);     // how to get a compiler error here?
    std::cout << f.x << std::endl;
}
```

**Is it possible to prevent the implicit conversion?**

The only way I could think of is to explicilty provide a constructor that takes an `int` and generates some kind of runtime error if the `int` is negative, but it would be nicer if I could get a compiler error for this.

I am almost sure, that there is a duplicate, but the closest I could find is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263267/why-does-c-allows-implicit-conversion-from-int-to-unsigned-int) which rather asks why the implicit conversion is allowed.

I am interested in both, C++11 and pre C++11 solutions, preferably one that would work in both.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Uniform initialization prevents narrowing.

It follows a (not working, as requested) example:

```
struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(unsigned int x) : x(x) {}
    unsigned int x;
};

int main() {
    Foo f = Foo{-1};
    std::cout << f.x << std::endl;
}
```

Simply get used to using the uniform initialization (`Foo{-1}` instead of `Foo(-1)`) wherever possible.

**EDIT**

As an alternative, as requested by the OP in the comments, a solution that works also with C++98 is to declare as `private` the constructors getting an `int` (`long int`, and so on).
No need actually to define them.
Please, note that `= delete` would be also a good solution, as suggested in another answer, but that one too is since C++11.

**EDIT 2**

I'd like to add one more solution, event though it's valid since C++11.
The idea is based on the suggestion of Voo (see the comments of Brian's response for further details), and uses SFINAE on constructor's arguments.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

struct S {
    template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type>
    S(T t) { }
};

int main() {
    S s1{42u};
    // S s2{42}; // this doesn't work
    // S s3{-1}; // this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: only possible in c++11, isnt it?

Comment: Yeah, did you say that you cannot use C++11?

Comment: no I didnt, but if there exists a solution that works nicely in pre c++11 and in post c++11 I prefer that one. Unfortunately in the biggest fraction of my code I cannot use c++11

Comment: and apart from c++11 or not, it doesnt really solve my problem, because `Foo f= Foo(-1);` is still allowed unless I force everybody using my code to use uniform initialization

Comment: Updated. Unfortunately, even `= delete` is since C++11.

Comment: @tobi303 I usually expect that a developer that doesn't use uniform initialization also knows what are the drawbacks. As an example, narrowing. You cannot force the others to write good code. :-)

Comment: actually I didnt realize that `=delete` is since c++11, sorry for the confusion and thanks for the tip with the private constructor.

Comment: Updated with a note about `=delete`, so as to help future readers. You are welcome.

Comment: @tobi303 _" but if there exists a solution that works nicely in pre c++11 and in post c++11 I prefer that one"_ How about `private: Foo(int x);`?

Comment: On a similar note, also be aware of the `explicit` keyword - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/explicit

Comment: @JesperJuhl ideone didnt complain about [explicit constructor called via `Foo(-1)`](http://ideone.com/wmmKRJ). I have to admit I am completely unfamiliar with most c++11 stuff

Comment: @tobi303 I know. I just thought it was relevant and related.

Comment: @tobi303 I've added one more suggestion, for the sake of curiosity. I hope you like it.

Comment: I edited my question trying to clarify this c++11 or pre c++11 issue (and removed the c++03 tag). Your answer still fits, actually better than before and I learned the lesson. I should be more explicit about this in the future ;)

Comment: No problem, it's the matter of updating an answer to add more details. ;-)

Answer (score 27):

You can force a compile error by deleting the undesired overload.

```
Foo(int x) = delete;
```

Comment: `Foo f(42)` would be prohibited (even if `42` is positive) (whereas `Foo f(42u)` works).

Comment: @Jarod42, true. But unvoidable :)

Comment: @Sergey For compile time constants we could avoid it with some SFINAE overloading and helper methods I guess, but I don't think one could combine the two methods as to disallow ints in general but allow int constants.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to be warned on *every* occurrence of such code, and you're using GCC, use the `-Wsign-conversion` option.

```
foo.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cc:8:19: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]
     Foo f = Foo(-1);     // how to get a compiler error here?
                   ^
```

If you want an error, use `-Werror=sign-conversion`.