# Why do implicit conversions in function parameters of same size not throw a warning?

Tags: c++, g++, implicit-conversion

See that example:

```
//test.cpp
#include <iostream>
void test(unsigned int i, int j) {
  std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
}
int main() {
  test(-1, -1);
  int x = -1;
  test(x,x);
  return 0;
}
```

with:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic test.cpp:
4294967295 -1
4294967295 -1
```

Why does gcc let that slip? And is there an option to detect such an implicit conversion?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make GCC warn on passing too-wide types to functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310108/can-i-make-gcc-warn-on-passing-too-wide-types-to-functions)

Comment: @Rakete1111 `unsigned int` is typically of the same width as `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered before. One of the reasons is because C allowed it, and c++ was meant to be backwards compatible. Some compilers will warn, though I tested on gcc 5.2 and it does not have an option to turn that warning on.

See: [Why does C++ allows implicit conversion from int to unsigned int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263267/why-does-c-allows-implicit-conversion-from-int-to-unsigned-int)

#

Just found from one of the other answers that you need to add the -Wsign-conversion flag. Seems -Wall should do that but doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, I found it. Misassumed that (-Wall -Wextra -W -Wpedantic -Wconversion) would cover it all. But in

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

the missing flag is: *-Wsign-conversion*

Comment: with `clang`, there is the very nice `-Weverything`.